# Firemonkey - how to place an Tlistitemimage in a circle

Tags: image, listview, bitmap, geometry, firemonkey

I have a listview with an images and data in each item. I want my image (which is a TlistitemImage to look like the below.

[image]

I can do this very easily by using Tcircle and using mycircle.fill.bitmap.bitmap, eg code below
lcircle.fill.Bitmap.Bitmap.LoadFromFile(TPath.GetDocumentsPath + PathDelim + 'test.png');
however i simply cannot create a circle for each listitem :-(

The other option i have is to use Tlistitemimage  - code below:

```
  LImage := TListItemImage.Create(mylistviewitem);
       LImage.Name := 'image';
       LImage.Align := TListItemAlign.Leading; // En Sað
       LImage.VertAlign := TListItemAlign.center; // Orta
       LImage.PlaceOffset.Y := 0;
       LImage.PlaceOffset.X := 0;
       Limage.width := 80;
       LImage.Height := 80;

       LImage.OwnsBitmap := True;
       LImage.Bitmap := TBitmap.Create(0,0);
```

Limage.Bitmap.LoadFromFile(TPath.GetDocumentsPath + PathDelim + 'test.png');

Now the idea i had was to then create the Tcircle  and make the parent of the circle the TListItemImage. That unfortunately does not work :-(

I have also tried doing this with the stylebook, creating a new style called listitemimagestyle and creating a tcircle within that style but that also does nothing.

Can someone please assist me?

Thank you - and yes, i am a noobie so be nice

Comment: noted, fixed, any idea how i can do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd use `TBitmap.CreateFromBitmapAndMask` in order to create your bitmap using a mask. The mask would be a black&white image that contains your circle.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create circle e.g on hidden tabitem and place image on this circle.
After that load image from file and assign screenshot to listitem bitmap

Item.Bitmap.Assign(Circle1.MakeScreenshot);

fmx form

```
    object Circle1: TCircle
        Align = Right
        Fill.Color = claSteelblue
        Margins.Left = 10.000000000000000000
        Margins.Top = 10.000000000000000000
        Margins.Right = 10.000000000000000000
        Margins.Bottom = 10.000000000000000000
        Position.X = 154.000000000000000000
        Position.Y = 10.000000000000000000
        Size.Width = 65.000000000000000000
        Size.Height = 65.000000000000000000
        Size.PlatformDefault = False
        Stroke.Kind = None
        object Image1: TImage
          MultiResBitmap.Height = 36
          MultiResBitmap.Width = 36
          MultiResBitmap.LoadSize = 2
          Align = Client
          Size.Width = 65.000000000000000000
          Size.Height = 65.000000000000000000
          Size.PlatformDefault = False
          WrapMode = Center
        end
   end
```